# Proximity query in Hive using ESRI geospatial library

Tags: hive, spatial-framework-hadoop, gis-tools-hadoop

I have one table of lines and one of points and need to find all pairs of line + point with a proximity < 10 meters.  The documentation for the ESRI hive library completely elides any discussion of units for distance, but I'm assuming it to be in fractional degrees in a WGS84 CRS.  Is there any way to get to linear distance using the Hive ST_* functions in an SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Try [ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/UDF-Accessors#st_geodesiclengthwgs84), as also discussed in [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/issues/53).

[Some samples can be found in this test script](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/blob/master/hive/test/st-geom-text.sql).

[Disclosure: collaborator]

Update:
As pointed out, the linked issue is point-point distance, while this question is line-point.  Perhaps adapt something to the effect of:
1. Coarse filter with ST_Distance on angular distance, with the distance limit chosen utilizing the bounds on latitude from the data extent.
2. For candidate matches, refine the angular distance limit per latitude of the candidate pairs, utilizing ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84, and apply ST_Distance again.  For more ideas on such technique, see the [trip-discovery sample in GIS Tools for Hadoop](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/09/vehicle-trip-discovery-with-gis-tools-for-hadoop/#creategrid)

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but I'm not clear how ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84  enables me to determine proximity of a point to a line.  Seems like I'd have to know the coordinates of the closest point on the line to use that function.   If ST_Buffer accepted linear distance as an argument I could check for intersection between lines and buffer regions, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to.

Comment: True, lines make it more difficult than points.